# Fortran Variable Naming

Tags: fortran

I am editing code that was given to me. Part of the editing is renaming variables. Most renames work well, but there are a few that cause errors during runtime. For example:

I intended to rename a variable from `fdat1` to `latestDate`, and it compiled fine. During runtime, I got an error from Windows saying the program stopped working. I decided to change the variable name in small steps to try to find out where the error was arising.
I went from `fdat1` -> `fdate1` -> `fdate2` -> `ldate2`. In changing the name to `ldate2`, the error showed up again. I decided to change the variable name to `fLatestDate`, and the program ran as expected.

I have `implicit none` in my program, so the first letter *shouldn't* be causing any issues. I'm wondering, is there something subtle about naming rules that I haven't come across yet? I have renamed several other variables to begin `latest`-, and each other name change caused no problems.

EDIT: `fdat1` occurs in nearly every file related to the program, so I'm going to use a different example, with the variable `idmul`. `idmul` is used only in `thresh`, and when I change the name to `powerCoeff`, the program quits itself. I can change the name to `*powerCoeff`, where `*` is any letter from d through i.

```
program thresh
implicit none
integer,parameter:: double=kind(1d0)
integer:: numStations,maxLines,nlo20
integer:: i,j,ctr,sysMonth,sysDay,sysHour
integer:: imid,ssumTrecent,ssumTantecedent,st
integer:: tptr,xptr,k,flag,timezoneOffset,sysYear
integer:: sysMinute,sysSeconds,lastDayOfMonth(12)
integer:: lineCtr,f24,sumTintensity,sumTavgIntensity
integer:: sumPrecip,maxDataGap,year 
integer:: stationCtr,unitNumber(10),Tintensity,Trecent
integer:: Tantecedent,rph,numNewLines,fmins
integer:: ev315,evid,evia,evi3,m
integer:: numContRowsExceed,evawid,resetAntMo,antda
integer,allocatable:: timestampMonth(:),da(:)
integer,allocatable:: hr(:),precip(:),ctrHolder(:)
integer,allocatable:: stationPtr(:),latestDay(:)
integer,allocatable:: latestMonth(:),latestHour(:)
integer,allocatable:: timestampYear(:),latestYear(:)
integer,allocatable:: mins(:),latestMinute(:) ! ,ifmt(:)
integer,allocatable:: pt315(:),ptid(:),ptia(:),pti3(:),ptawid(:)
integer,allocatable:: tlenx(:),numTimestampsHolder(:)
integer :: tRainfallBegan,tRainfallEnd
integer :: TstormGap,minTStormGap
integer :: TavgIntensity,numPlotPoints,numPlotPoints2
integer :: AWICompOffset,numTimestamps
integer :: ctr315,ctrid,ctria,cum15dRainfallCtr,ctra
integer :: ctri,diffSysMinTimestampMinute,AWIExceedCtr,AWIIntensCtr
integer :: ctri3
character (len=255),allocatable:: dataLocation(:)
character (len=255):: outputFile,pathThlast
character (len=224):: outputFolder
character (len=80):: header
character (len=50), allocatable:: stationLocation(:)
character (len=31):: junk
character (len=31):: archiveFile='ThArchive'
character (len=31):: defaultOutputFile='threshout.txt'
character (len=31):: dgOutputfile='dgthresh.txt'
character (len=31):: updateFile='ThUpdate.txt'
character (len=20), allocatable:: datimb(:)
character (len=17), allocatable:: datim(:)
character (len=11):: fLatestDate,revdate
character (len=10):: fdat,sysTime
character (len=8):: timeSeriesPlotFile='ThTSplot'
character (len=8):: sysDate,ThlastStationNo,vrsn
character (len=8), allocatable:: stationNumber(:)
character (len=6):: psn(2) !,snum
character (len=6):: timeSeriesExceedFile='ThTime'
character (len=5):: fLatestTime
character (len=4):: plotFormat
character (len=3)::month(12)
character (len=2)::unt,powerUnit
character (len=1):: tb,pd,cm
logical ::lgyr,match,stats,lsfil,powerSwitch,flagRealtime
real:: slope3day15day,intercept3day15day,in2mm
real:: idmul,idexp,inia,slia,kd,fieldCap,decayFactor
real:: aw,AWIconversion,evp(12),floatPrecip,AWIThresh
real:: awimx,sum3mx,rntsymx
real:: x,polynomArr(6)
real,allocatable:: threshIntensityDuration(:),threshAvgExceed(:)
real,allocatable:: AWI(:),AWI_0(:)
real,allocatable:: sumTrecent(:),sumTantecedent(:)
real,allocatable:: intensity(:),dur(:)
real,allocatable:: runIntensity(:),deficitSurplus3d15d(:)!,antst(:)
real,allocatable:: sum3s(:),sum15s(:),intsys(:),durs(:)
real,allocatable:: srunIntensity(:),def315s(:)
real,allocatable:: sthreshIntensityDuration(:)
real,allocatable:: sthreshAvgIntensity(:)!,antsts(:)
real (double):: dlast,trfbeg,trfend,dgap
real (double),allocatable:: dtdate1904eachLine(:),tdate1904last(:)
real (double),allocatable:: tdate1904newest(:)
real (double),allocatable:: tdate1904stormBeg(:),tdate1904stormEnd(:)
```

Comment: It's not sufficient to have `implicit none` in your program, it must be present in every scope within which names are, or may be, declared.  And I don't believe you when you write that you have changed several other variable names by prefixing the string `latest-` since `-` is not a valid character in a Fortran name.

Comment: I mean, the hyphen is there only to indicate that it's being used as a prefix. I have `implicit none` in every subroutine, as well.

Comment: That changing a variable name that begins with "f" to two different names beginning with "l" causes a problem suggests that implicit typing is in effect somewhere.  To make absolutely sure that `implicit none` is in effect everywhere, I suggest using a compiler option.  Most Fortran compilers have an option to activate `implicit none` whether or not that is specified in the source code.  In gfortran the option is `-fimplicit-none`.

Comment: I don't know if variable names have an impact on their arrangement in memory, but if it would be the case, this could also be a symptom of out-of-bound array access... Could you try an option like -fbounds-check?